# Group of checkbox with initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two checkbox.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="chbR" /> % Retain</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" class="chbP" /> % Passing</label>
```

Only one of both can be selected as the same time

If cb1 is selected and user click cb1, cb1 need to be unselected
If cb2 is selected and user click cb2, cb2 need to be unselected

If cb1 is selected and user click cb2, cb1 need to be unselted
If cb2 is selected and user click cb1, cb2 need to be unselted
http://jsfiddle.net/5o47bgzc/

tried with click and change event but it's like a third state is needed

when the event occur, previous state is not available

any other way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you want a radio button...

Comment: no, need to able to uncheck both

Comment: That just means you want a radio with some magik, :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by making each checkbox's change turn off the checked state of the other:

```js
$(".chbR").change(function() {
  $(".chbP").prop('checked', false);
});

$(".chbP").change(function() {
  $(".chbR").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="chbR" /> % Retain</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" class="chbP" /> % Passing</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

So this logic uses radio buttons, and keeps track of the value that is selected.  If you click on the radio that is already selected, it un-selects it.

```js
$(function(){
  var lastValue = '';
  
  $('.chb')
    .on('click', function(e){
      if (lastValue === e.target.value) {
        e.target.checked = false;
        lastValue = '';
      }
    })
    .on('change', function(e){
      lastValue = e.target.value;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="cb" value="retain" class="chb chbR" /> % Retain</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cb" value="passing" class="chb chbP" /> % Passing</label>
```